# SQL Statement returns 500 Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT_WS (" ",Firstname, Surname) AS FullName FROM Applicant WHERE AppID=10010";
```

This statement returns Error 500 on my page despite of that it is a completely correct statement. I run this query on Sequel Pro and it is returning exactly what I need.

I tried a simple query and its working fine:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cases";
```

I don't know why PHP is doing that. Maybe an extra pair of eyes can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong double quotes sequence

```
  $sql = "SELECT CONCAT_WS (' ',Firstname, Surname) AS FullName 
       FROM Applicant WHERE AppID=10010";
```

you must a different  quote char inside the query string

Comment: Now I feel stupid for posting that :) I should have a break soon. Thank you sir, for your answer!